# Direct database interaction with memory - how it works?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, buffer-pool, dbms

I am reading a book on databases and a chapter in it talks about buffer manager and it's replacement strategies.

I've noticed that the DBMS interacts directly with memory, as opposed to asking OS to interact with virtual memory. Is that correct? How exactly does this direct communication takes place? How much of memory is DBMS allowed to allocate? I've never been exposed to such low level function calls and I'd love to see some explanations and examples of it.

Getting this kind of info is kinda troublesome to find on google if you don't know the correct keywords to search for.

Comment: "buffer pool" is the correct term to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about MySQL/MariaDB with ENGINE=InnoDB only.  (That is virtually the only Engine in use today.)

- All InnoDB activity happens in the buffer_pool.
- All data and each secondary index is composed of 16KB blocks.
- Those blocks are brought into the buffer_pool as needed, and flushed out as needed.
- It uses a LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm for controlling which blocks to bump out.  (There are minor tweaks to LRU, so it is not *exactly* LRU.)

Hence, it is very important go give InnoDB *most* of RAM, then let it do its thing.  A simple rule of thumb:  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of RAM.  For *most* applications, that is the most important setting and the only one that needs to be changed from the default.

Setting the buffer_pool too large could lead to swapping.  But, since InnoDB treats it as a big array, that could cause a terrible amount of swapping, hence slowing down MySQL/MariaDB terribly.

InnoDB has threads for reading writing blocks.  In particular, flushing to disk is somewhat done "in the background".  This allows an `INSERT` to appear to be faster than it really is.

I discuss memory allocation further in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory)

Using "virtual memory" for accessing a file is a lazy way to do things.  It works OK for simple cases.  However, a database engine needs to be efficient and fast.  When the code knows the access pattern, it is best to use an access method that is tuned for such.

For example, if you are going to read sequentially through a file, it is best (for memory management) to ping-ping between two 'small' buffers; one being read into and one being parsed.  (A single "circular" buffer is a good alternative.)

> How exactly does this direct communication takes place?

Because everything is in 16KB blocks, there is a number that uniquely identifies such.  It is rather large (20? bytes).  It includes at least the "tablespace" number, and block number within the table space.  This is taken modulo the number of buffer_pool_instances to decide which instance to look in.

Within a block, there are rows of the table or rows of a secondary index, or rows of a node in the B+Tree (see Wikipedia) that it represents.

If the block is not in the buffer_pool, it must wait while a read occurs.  But, before the read can occur, there *might* need to be a write to flush out some block.  Normally, a background thread(s) flushes out "dirty" blocks so that there is always some free blocks in the buffer_pool.  ("Free" or "easily removed" because they are not dirty.)

Comment: Your knowledge is much appreciated. `Setting the buffer_pool too large could lead to swapping`. So `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is a max memory consumption possible. OS can devour it if it decides to? Also, I am reading `Database management systems` from Ramikrisknan and Gherke and while the book is the best I found, it does not go into details as much as I would like to. In other words.. it is written from the standpoint of DBA, not DBMS programmer (there is zero implementation code in it). What resource, besides docs, would you recommend to help me get a deeper understanding of DBMS?

Comment: @sanjihan - No.  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the max _for that one use of memory_.  There are many other uses; they are not included there, and generally are small.  It is part of mysqld's memory; the OS cannot touch it except by swapping.  If you want gory details, read blogs by jcole (Jeremy Cole).  Meanwhile, I am happy to give you a higher level description.